# Issue with CheckFileInfo endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, ms-wopi

So we are a cloud-storage partner, and my `CheckFileInfo` is called by office online, but after that, I was under the impression that the `wopi/files/{id}/contents` endpoint should be hit, but it just never gets to that point. I've checked several different checkFileInfo implementations and can't figure out the issue. Is there something I am missing?

This is the endpoint implementation (thanks to this repository https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost)

```c#
[HttpGet("wopi/files/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCheckFileInfo(string id)
{
    IWopiFile wopiFile = wopiStorageProvider.GetWopiFile(id);
    JsonResult checkFileInfoView = new JsonResult(wopiFile.GetCheckFileInfo(null, HostCapabilities), null);
    return new JsonResult(wopiFile.GetCheckFileInfo(null, HostCapabilities), null);
}
```

Here is the json, that is returned:

```c#
{
    "baseFileName": "test.docx",
    "ownerId": "test1",
    "size": 14058,
    "userId": "test1",
    "version": "2023-02-20T13:46:36",
    "lastModifiedTime": "2023-02-20T13:46:36.3436458Z",
    "fileExtension": ".docx",
    "fileNameMaxLength": 0,
    "breadcrumbBrandName": null,
    "breadcrumbBrandUrl": null,
    "breadcrumbDocName": null,
    "breadcrumbDocUrl": null,
    "breadcrumbFolderName": null,
    "breadcrumbFolderUrl": null,
    "clientUrl": null,
    "closeButtonClosesWindow": false,
    "closeUrl": null,
    "disableBrowserCachingOfUserContent": false,
    "allowAdditionalMicrosoftServices": false,
    "allowErrorReportPrompt": false,
    "allowExternalMarketplace": false,
    "disablePrint": false,
    "disableTranslation": false,
    "downloadUrl": null,
    "fileEmbedCommandUrl": null,
    "fileSharingUrl": null,
    "fileUrl": null,
    "fileVersionUrl": null,
    "hostAuthenticationId": null,
    "hostEditUrl": null,
    "hostEmbeddedEditUrl": null,
    "hostEmbeddedViewUrl": null,
    "hostName": null,
    "hostNotes": null,
    "hostRestUrl": null,
    "hostViewUrl": null,
    "irmPolicyDescription": null,
    "irmPolicyTitle": null,
    "presenceProvider": null,
    "presenceUserId": null,
    "privacyUrl": null,
    "protectInClient": false,
    "signInUrl": null,
    "readOnly": false,
    "restrictedWebViewOnly": false,
    "sha256": "k50Ci3h/VE0klyULDGaQLvH3RWWMLgHqkxQXURRmeSc=",
    "uniqueContentId": null,
    "signoutUrl": null,
    "supportsCoauth": true,
    "supportsCobalt": false,
    "supportsFolders": false,
    "supportsContainers": false,
    "supportsLocks": false,
    "supportsGetLock": false,
    "supportsExtendedLockLength": false,
    "supportsEcosystem": false,
    "supportsGetFileWopiSrc": false,
    "supportedShareUrlTypes": null,
    "supportsScenarioLinks": false,
    "supportsSecureStore": false,
    "supportsFileCreation": false,
    "supportsUpdate": false,
    "supportsRename": false,
    "supportsDeleteFile": false,
    "supportsUserInfo": false,
    "userInfo": null,
    "tenantId": null,
    "termsOfUseUrl": null,
    "timeZone": null,
    "isAnonymousUser": true,
    "isEduUser": false,
    "licenseCheckForEditIsEnabled": false,
    "userCanAttend": false,
    "userCanNotWriteRelative": false,
    "userCanPresent": false,
    "userCanWrite": false,
    "userCanRename": false,
    "userFriendlyName": null,
    "userPrincipalName": null,
    "webEditingDisabled": false
}
```

This would be the endpoint, that I would expect to be hit right after returning from checkFileInfo:

```c#
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpGet("wopi/files/{id}/contents")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile(string id)
{  
    IWopiFile wopiFile = wopiStorageProvider.GetWopiFile(id);
    return new FileStreamResult(wopiFile.GetReadStream(), "application/octet-stream");
}
```

Is there a missinterpretation regarding the endpoint calls or is my implementation missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether there are any incoming requests to the WopiHost at all? Maybe they get filtered out by the AuthNZ middleware.

Try putting breakpoints in the [WopiAuthorizationHandler](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost/blob/52b27b6d214eebfc2fd293670879dbc50857918d/src/WopiHost.Core/Security/Authorization/WopiAuthorizationHandler.cs#L33) and the [AccessTokenHandler](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost/blob/52b27b6d214eebfc2fd293670879dbc50857918d/src/WopiHost.Core/Security/Authentication/AccessTokenHandler.cs#L24) and see if they get hit and what happens next.